# What is the correct way to select and group JSON objects with a common element value in cosmos sql api

Tags: node.js, group-by, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to run aggregate stats from a collection of documents. I'm new to denormalised databases and am not clear how I should structure a query or sproc to get aggregate the data I need. I have tried group by, subqueries and other methods, but not sure where I am going wrong.

My data looks like this:

```
[{
    "_partitionKey": "transcript2",
    "docHeader": {
        "docType": "Transcript",
        "id": "transcriptID1",
        "messageId": "XX0001",
        "activity": "message"
        "content": "content 1"
    }
},
{
    "_partitionKey": "transcript2",
    "docHeader": {
        "docType": "Transcript",
        "id": "transcriptID1",
        "messageId": "XX0001",
        "activity": "message"
        "content": "content 2"
    }
},
{
    "_partitionKey": "transcript2",
    "docHeader": {
        "docType": "Transcript",
        "id": "transcriptID2",
        "messageId": "XX0009",
        "activity": "message"
        "content": "content 1"
    }
}]
```

I need to be able to return only documents that have a shared messageId.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I need to be able to return only documents that have a shared
>   messageId.

If my understanding is right,you want to get those documents where the `messageId` is contained by the `count(messageId)>1` messages list.However, aggregation or group by are not supported in the `where` clause.So,i'm afraid that you need to implement your needs by below 3 steps.

Step1,you could get the messageId and messageCount group by messageId.

Sample Code:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        /// The Azure Cosmos DB endpoint for running this GetStarted sample.
        private string EndpointUrl = "https://***.documents.azure.com:443/";

        /// The primary key for the Azure DocumentDB account.
        private string PrimaryKey = "***";

        // The Cosmos client instance
        private CosmosClient cosmosClient;

        // The database we will create
        private Database database;

        // The container we will create.
        private Container container;

        // The name of the database and container we will create
        private string databaseId = "db";
        private string containerId = "coll";

        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Beginning operations...\n");
                Program p = new Program();
                await p.GetStartedDemoAsync();

            }
            catch (CosmosException de)
            {
                Exception baseException = de.GetBaseException();
                Console.WriteLine("{0} error occurred: {1}", de.StatusCode, de);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("End of demo, press any key to exit.");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        public async Task GetStartedDemoAsync()
        {
            // Create a new instance of the Cosmos Client
            this.cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(EndpointUrl, PrimaryKey);
            await this.CreateDatabaseAsync();
            await this.CreateContainerAsync();
            await this.QueryItemsAsync();
        }

        private async Task CreateDatabaseAsync()
        {
            // Create a new database
            this.database = await this.cosmosClient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(databaseId);
            Console.WriteLine("Created Database: {0}\n", this.database.Id);
        }


        private async Task CreateContainerAsync()
        {
            // Create a new container
            this.container = await this.database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerId, "/group");
            Console.WriteLine("Created Container: {0}\n", this.container.Id);
        }



        private async Task QueryItemsAsync()
        {

            var sqlQueryText = "SELECT count(1) as messageCount,c.docHeader.messageId as messageId FROM c group by c.docHeader.messageId ";

            Console.WriteLine("Running query: {0}\n", sqlQueryText);

            QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(sqlQueryText);
            FeedIterator<Result> queryResultSetIterator = this.container.GetItemQueryIterator<Result>(queryDefinition);

            List<Result> families = new List<Result>();

            while (queryResultSetIterator.HasMoreResults)
            {
                FeedResponse<Result> currentResultSet = await queryResultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();
                foreach (Result family in currentResultSet)
                {
                    families.Add(family);
                    Console.WriteLine("\tMessageCount {0}\n", family.messageCount);
                    //Console.WriteLine("\tId {0}\n", family.Id);
                    Console.WriteLine("\ttMessageId {0}\n", family.messageId);
                }
            }
        }

    }



    public class Result
    {

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "messageCount")]
        public int messageCount { get; set; }


        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "messageId")]
        public string messageId { get; set; }
    }

}
```

[image]

Step2: Loop above list get the messageId list which count>1

Step3: Then execute sql :

`SELECT c.* from c where ARRAY_CONTAINS(messageIdList, c.docHeader.messageId,true)`